# sql week keyword not include the early year days

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get birth days of people in the week. Today is January 3. When I am trying to get this week birthdays, it doesn't include the december birthdays that is belong to this week. My sql query is as follows. What is the wrong with that?

```
select id, birth, full_name, mobile, email 
from house_holders 
where Week(DATE_ADD( birth, INTERVAL year(NOW()) - year(birth) YEAR),1) = week(NOW(),1);
```

Comment: please some one help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

With the condition `Week(DATE_ADD( birth, INTERVAL year(NOW()) - year(birth) YEAR),1) = week(NOW(),1);` you will get only the birth days related to today.

This happens because the result of `Week(DATE_ADD( '2014-12-29', INTERVAL year(NOW()) - year('2014-12-29') YEAR),1)` is `53`, while the result of `week(NOW(),1);` is `1`, and then you will never get the results you want. Indeed dates like `'2014-12-29'` are considered and evaluated as part of the last week of year 2014, not the current one of year 2015.

If you want to get the birth days of the current week, you should filter the birth days using **`DATE_ADD() function`** together with the **`DAYOFWEEK() function`**:

```
SELECT id, birth
FROM house_holders 
WHERE birth >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1-DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) DAY)
AND birth <= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7-DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) DAY);
```

See a demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/?_escaped_fragment_=6/cafba/1#!2/3dc388/7).

Comment: When year is in 1989 or somthing not belong to 2014 or 2015, it doesn't work. I want to check birthdays. Thank you for your answer. Please update this for any year.

Comment: @GayanFernando Indeed the solution is related to birth days of the current week, as you asked: "I am trying to get birth days of people in the week" or "When I am trying to get this week birthdays, it doesn't include the december birthdays that is belong to this week.". You should clarify what you really want to achieve. What do you mean with "I want to check birthdays"?

Comment: If someone's birthday is in 30-12-1989, I want to include this person also in output. Not only birthdays in 2014 and 2015 that belong to this week.

Comment: @GayanFernando You can then simply replace `CURDATE()` with the date corresponding to the week you want to check. Example: `SELECT id, birth
FROM house_holders 
WHERE birth >= DATE_ADD('1989-12-30', INTERVAL 1-DAYOFWEEK('1989-12-30') DAY)
AND birth <= DATE_ADD('1989-12-30', INTERVAL 7-DAYOFWEEK('1989-12-30') DAY);`